# AWS Copilot - deploy/create a https endpoint instead

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-fargate

I have gone through several aws copilot tutorials, example, https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/developing-an-application-based-on-multiple-microservices-using-the-aws-copilot-and-aws-fargate/

Every example results in the generation of a http endpoint, what do I need to do in copilot to get a https endpoint deployed instead?

To be clear, I am not looking to define a domain in route 53, just looking for the generated endpoint to be https.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

answered my own question, looking at the copilot github issues section, at present, https endpoint is only possible by defining a domain.
https://github.com/aws/copilot-cli/issues/2071